# How to select random data in a dataset in R

Tags: r, observational-study

I have an excel with 5 thousand data, i want to select just 300 random datas from this dataset. what command do I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample rownumbers ....

```
index <- Sample(1:N,100)
Subset <- my_dataframe[index,]
```

And use stack overflow for R questions.